# How to add noise to these random straight lines in 3D?

Tags: function-construction, graphics3d, random, version-7, random-process

Here's a code that draws a pack of random straight lines in 3D:

```
Corde[s_, x0_, y0_, z0_, u_, phi_] := {
  x0 + s Sqrt[1 - u^2] Cos[phi],
  y0 + s Sqrt[1 - u^2] Sin[phi],
  z0 + s u
  }

x0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
y0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
z0[n_] := RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
u0[n_] := RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
phi0[n_] := RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];

Cordes[s_] := Table[
  Corde[s, x0[n], y0[n], z0[n], u0[n], phi0[n]], {n, 1, 10}]

Enchevetrement = 
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Cordes[s], {s, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 2];

Show[Enchevetrement,
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 Axes -> True,
 Ticks -> None,
 AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.25],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
 ImageSize -> {700, 700}
 ]
```

Preview:

[image]

I would like to make them looking like some kind of **natural random walks** by adding noise to the lines.  The result should be smooth looking (no discontinuities, the curves should stay smooth).  The randomness resolution should be an option to increase the paths complexity.

In other words: each straight line should get some random wavy noise.

Take note that I'm using **Mathematica 7.0**, and I can't upgrade the machine to a newer version of Mathematica.  So the code modifications should stay close to the original code, with just a few new simple functions.  Nothing fancy.

---

**EDIT:**  Using kglr's code below, I get what appears to be closed curves, with a pesky straight line as shown below:

[image]

I need to get rid of these long straight lines...

Comment: try replacing `BSplineCurve[RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3] + # & /@ x]` with `BSplineCurve[RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3] + # & /@ x, SplineClosed -> False]`?

Comment: @kglr, I tried this option and it does nothing!  The straight line is still there.

Comment: can you try `BSplineCurve[Rest@Most[RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3] + # & /@ x]]`?

Comment: can you post the output from `SeedRandom[1];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Corde[s, x0[n], y0[n], z0[n], u0[n], phi0[n]], {s, -20, 
   20}, PlotPoints -> 20][[1]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
a = 1; pp = 50;

SeedRandom[1]
Enchevetrement =  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Cordes[s], {s, -20, 20}, 
   PlotPoints -> pp, MaxRecursion -> 1];


Show[Enchevetrement /. Line[x_] :> BSplineCurve[RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3] + # & /@ x], 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> None, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.25], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, 
 ImageSize -> {700, 700}]
```

[image]

Play with `a` and `pp` to control the amplitude and frequency to get various shapes: For example, with `pp = 200` and `a = .3` we get

[image]

Use `a = 1; pp = 200;` and replace `BSplineCurve[RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3] + # & /@ x]` with `BSplineCurve[({Abs@#, ##2} & @@ RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3]) + # & /@ x]` to prevent bending backward in x direction:

[image]

Comment: That's very nice!  Please, could you elaborate on the #&/@x ?  I don't understand this part.  Also, on my system, I get a long straight line added to the random noisy lines, like a closing line.  I'm unable to get rid of it yet.

Comment: @Cham, the pure  function ` foo = RandomReal[{-a, a}, 3] + # &` (which could be defined alternatively as `foo[arg_]:=RandomReal[{-a,a},3}+ arg`) is `Map`ped (`/@)` on the list `x` (which is a list of triples).

Comment: Re "long straight line added to the random noisy lines", it may be version/os related. If you update your question with a picture showing the problem,  may be  someone with version 7 may be able identify a solution.

Comment: Oh no !  This is weird!  I get the straight lines if I use Axes -> False, or Axes -> None. Using Axes -> True removes the issue !!

Comment: If I leave the option Axes -> True, but translate out the axes, the issue is back again !  This is odd.  Looks like a bug to me.